# Pyodbc cannot resolve localhost, but work on IP address 127.0.0.1

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, odbc, pyodbc

I use Pyodbc in Python3.8 to connect to the SQL Server on localhost.

In the connection string, I can connect to the database using IP address(127.0.0.1), but I got an error when using localhost. How to solve this issue?

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
            "Server=127.0.0.1;" # this works
            "Database=**;"
            "UID=**;"
            "PWD=**;"
           )
```

If I replace the IP address with localhost, it's failed.

```
cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
            "Server=localhost;" # failed
            "Database=**;"
            "UID=**;"
            "PWD=**;"
           )
```

error:

```
      1 cnxn_str = ("Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};"
      2             "Server=localhost;"
      3             "Database=**;"
      4             "UID=**;"
      5             "PWD=**;"
      6            )
----> 7 cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxn_str)

OperationalError: ('HYT00', '[HYT00] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Login timeout expired (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I can ping localhost on my local, and localhost works in browsers.

```
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.061 ms
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.051 ms
```

etc/hosts:

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
```

Comment: Your etc/hosts file has the answer: `::1             localhost` is mapping the IPv6 loopback address to the `localhost` name. Your SQL Server must only be listening on the IPv4 address, 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, how do I resolve it and make localhost work? Do you mean I should remove ::1 in etc/hosts file?

Comment: Yes, comment it out by placing a `#` (octothorp) at the start of the last line. You have `127.0.0.1 localhost` earlier in the hosts file, but it is getting redefined by `::1 localhost` on the last line. Or you could change your connection string to use `"Server=127.0.0.1;"`.

Comment: Hi @AlwaysLearning, I've commented out `# ::1      localhost`, but still localhost isn't resolved in the connection string.
My SQL Server is listening on `127.0.0.1:1433`. And I can always use localhost to access the db in DBeaver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MS ODBC driver resolves `localhost` to your machine name, but your hostname doesn't resolve to `127.0.0.1` or `::1`, hence the issue. You can add an alias with your hostname in `/etc/hosts`:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost   YOUR-HOSTNAME
```

Now, I understand that normally you should be able to ping your hostname and it should resolve to the same IP as localhost without having to handle this manually in the hosts config, but that's a different issue.

---

Related:

https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/1125

https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/2075